# How to connect the vertices of two separate objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, workflow, mirror

While I was modelling a bird I ended up in a dead end and I do not know how to get out. I created the eyes of my bird as two separate objects using the mirror modifier, but now I can no longer connect the eyes vertices with those of the rest of the face because I have two different objects.

If I join the eyes vertices with the face/body vertices using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> I will lose the mirror modifier, but I don't want to loose the mirror modifier for the eyes.  So I don't see a way out from this situation.

[image: bird's picture]

Comment: apply mirror first. now you can join it with CTRL + J

Comment: I know,but if I do it,I will lose the mirror feature and I have to model two eyes instead of only one. As you can see from the picture,I need to complete the modelling of the face,but i can't do it if I can't connect the eyes vertices with the rest of the face vertices...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not work with one eye and your faced joined up and mirror afterwards?.

Highlight the eye vertices in edit mode with  with <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>B</kbd> then separate by selection with <kbd>P</kbd> and apply the mirror to new object creating your second eye. As long as it lines up nice it would get you your mirror option back.